# Can anyone recommend a beginning Ruby on Rails tutorial that doesn't rely on scaffolding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just started learning Ruby on Rails, and all the tutorials and books I've used rely on scaffolding to get started. I've written two simple apps but I still can't figure out how to independently write a database-driven app without using scaffolding, and yet from what I've read online most professional Rails developers don't use it. Are there any tutorials that would help a newbie create their first app without scaffolding?

Answer (score 3):

This one http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/the-intro-to-rails-screencast-i-wish-i-had/  is pretty good and helpful.

"Rails 3 in Action" is a good resource (I've even bought it ;)), one thing I hate about it is a sort of enforced usage of Cucumber.

Cucumber is a great tool, worth mentioning, but it is used all over the book and it clutters the narrative terribly. I would like to have Cucumber-free version of the book and I belive that most beginners would prefer the same.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl: http://www.railstutorial.org/

Best resource for Rails learning I've come across, whether in paper or online.

Comment: Thanks.. I've been following that and getting frustrated with it, but maybe I just need to stick it out..

Comment: Definitely follow through with it.  It starts with scaffolding, but only as a basic introduction.  The real meat of the tutorial is an app that doesn't use scaffolding at all.  If anything in the tutorial doesn't work as expected even though you followed the instructions, there's a Q&A or feedback sort of section on that site where you can ask for help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently writing a book called [Rails 3 in Action](http://manning.com/katz) that sounds like it would "answer" your question.

Whilst the first chapter *does* cover scaffolding (just for a "quick win"), the rest of the book goes through and teaches you how to develop an application using the exact same process that people in the real world do.

You'll learn Rails, Cucumber and RSpec, along with the other gems that we pick up along the way of developing the application.

Give it a shot and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Check out some of the older Railscasts.